# Loading a list view inside a main xaml page on click event of button in xamarin

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been developing a xamarin hybrid app. I have a content page with a button and I want to load a list view inside the content page on click event of the button.Function to get data from API

```
    public static async Task<List<TranslationWords>> GetTranslation()
    {           
        string url = "";//api url here

        dynamic results = await DataService.GetDataFromService(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (results != null)
        {

            var wordsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TranslationWords>>(results);
            Console.WriteLine(wordsList);
            return wordsList;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    public static async Task<List<dynamic>> GetDataFromService(string url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var json = "{'word':'wide','type':'eng_to_tam'}";
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

        dynamic data = null;
        if (response != null)
        {
            string res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);    
            return data;           

        } else {
            //code to handle null response
         }   

       }
```

### code for master page detail xaml

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout Padding="10">

    <Switch HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Toggled="Switcher_Toggled"></Switch>
    <Label Text="Enter a Word:" />
    <Entry x:Name="wordToFind" Text="" />
    <Button x:Name="searchButton" Text="Search" Clicked="Load_List"/>
    <ContentView x:Name="MainPageContainer" 
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                     />           
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

### list view xaml

The list view is placed inside a content view(MainPageContainer) in the main page.Content view will be loaded with data when the button in master detail page is clicked

```
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout
                     Padding="10">
                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding TamilWord}"
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                        FontSize="16" />
                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding TamilMeaning}"
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                        FontSize="13" />
                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding EnglishTranslation}"
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                        FontSize="13" />


                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

### data binding in .cs file

```
     public List<TranslationWords> Words;


    public TransList ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        Words = Core.GetTranslation().Result;  //method to get data from api
        transListView.ItemsSource = Words;
    }
```

Comment: is there a specific reason why your ListView is in an extra ContentView? Is there anything more that has to be shown or is it just the ListView? If it is just the ListView, why is it not directly in the page?

Comment: I just wanted to get the list view in the main page itself. Created a content view inside the main page and loaded the list view into the content view on button's click event

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to set the `IsVisible` to `False` and in your on click event to `True`. If "load" means "show".

Your XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XFIntro"
         x:Class="XFIntro.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Click" Clicked="ListClicked" />

    <ListView x:Name="LView" IsVisible="False"/>
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

The Code Behin

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LView.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "baz"};
    }

    void ListClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LView.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

If load means you want to load items onto the listview with the click event, the code is nearly the same, just use
`LView.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "baz"};`
in your click event now and set the ListView always to visible

Comment: This is will be in the case of static list. What if the list view to be loaded dynamically from a JSON which is received from an API.

Comment: then just load your items from the API and if they are loaded set them to your ItemsSource?! You could provide a bit more code of your project in order to explain yourself a bit better...